# AWS Kibana search with special symbols

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana

Currently, I'm using Kibana + Elasticsearch on AWS  (v. 5.1). I can't search for specific symbols like `-` or `/`, mostly I want to find specific URLs in the logs which I store in `Elasticsearch`, but `Elasticsearch` is ignoring those symbols, from the `Elasticsearch` documentation I understood that's because of the standard analyzer is in use. But If I'm checking the current analyzer status I can see this message for the following request `GET /_analyzer`

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
                "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: text is missing;"
            }
        ],
        "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
        "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: text is missing;"
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

[here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/aes-supported-es-operations.html#es_version_5_1) it says that the entrypoint is supported, but still does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The analyzer is a setting per field and the command you're trying to run would [analyze a given text](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html).

What you are interested in is the mapping, for example: `GET /my-index/my-type/_mapping`.

There's a very good answer to your general question about analyzed and not analyzed fields and how to use them in Kibana at https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-use-slash-to-search-in-discovery/92340/2

Comment: Thanks to your link I got it in the mapping but it does not appear in Kibana UI (Discover) even though it's visible in Management :(

Comment: The `*.raw` fields are not visible in Discover, but you can still use them in the search bar

Comment: If I'm sending the req like that `GET /elblogs*/elb-access-logs/_search?q=user_agent:Google` I have result and if like that `GET /elblogs*/elb-access-logs/_search?q=user_agent.raw:Google` 0 result

Comment: If you're using `.raw` it needs to be a full match — I guess the `user_agent` contains more than just "Google" then using the analyzed (not raw) field is what you want. Though your original question mentioned `-` and `/`

Comment: My idea is to be able to search in user_agent not only GoogleBot, but Ads-GoogleBot etc.. so I need sometimes full match, sometimes I would liek to use kinda regex to catch `-GoogleBot`

Comment: Ok, then you'll need an analyzed field. IMO this is developing away from the original question. If you still have trouble, open a new question with sample data, mapping, and the queries you want to run :)

Comment: I think your answer helped me a lot, now it looks like I start getting the result :-). Thanks